# How to store away toner powder long time?

Tags: printer, laser-printer, toner

I bought a cheap toner powder 200g in a plastic bottle. I opened it once for refill and it still has enough powder for few more refills.

**How should I keep the powder bottle stored long term?**

Comment: not sure why people are voting to close, this is a legitimate question

Comment: Superuser is not about "electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer." (http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) This is about storage of toner powder, even a further step away from computers.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: Refilling ink/toner cartidges is on-topic (see http://meta.superuser.com/a/10890/364367), so proper storage of the material to do that would seem to also be on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

From this [article](http://www.247inktoner.com/blog/post/2012/03/31/How-long-can-you-store-toner-cartridges.aspx)

- Do not store your discount toner in temperatures in excess of 95 degrees  - -- Fahrenheit (35 degrees Celsius) or lower than 50 degrees Fahrenheit (10 degrees Celsius). These are numbers that generally apply to most cartridges.
- Keep your toner cartridges horizontal. Do not store your cartridges vertically.
- For long-term storage, keep the toner cartridges in their original packaging (cardboard box and sealed bag).
- Try to keep the relative humidity where your cartridges are being stored between 45 percent and 80 percent.
- Do not store your toner cartridges in any place that experiences rapid and extreme fluctuations in temperature or humidity.
- Avoid subjecting your toner cartridges to direct sunlight, even for short periods of time.
- Avoid storing or keeping your toner cartridges in places that are dusty or where dust may gather.
- Do not store your toner cartridges in your car or vehicle – not even the trunk – for long periods of time.
- Do not store your toner cartridges anywhere corrosive gases may be present.
- Toner cartridges can be affected by salty air. Try to keep your toner cartridges out of air that may have high saline concentrations.

Comment: Just to clarify: I am asking about a bottle of powder, not a cartridge. But I assume things like temp/humidity apply just the same.